# CSS scroll snap with mouse does not work in Safari but works in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, safari, scroll-snap

Here's a simple scroll snap demo:

```css
.scroll {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```

**What I expect to happen**

Scrolling the scrollbar with the mouse in desktop Safari should snap to an item.

**What happens**

Scroll snap has no effect in Safari but works in Firefox and Chrome. But it does work in Safari if I scroll with the trackpad.

---

This seems like such a simple issue and I feel silly for resorting to asking such a trivial question on Stackoverflow, but I've been googling for the past 30 mins and I can't seem to find anyone else with the same issue or some documentation that explains this behavior. Even WebKit's scroll snap [demo page](https://webkit.org/demos/scroll-snap/) does not indicate that it should only work on iOS or with the trackpad; why don't they mention this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have the same issue, Did you ever got it working?

Comment: I'm wondering the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an already fixed bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=146696